# Axiomatic Characterization of Convergence of Filters in a Topological Space

Tags: general-topology, filters

I am studying **Topology , specially nets and filters** from K.D Joshi.There while solving exercise I came through a problem at the page 247, which is [image: of axiomatic Characterization of Convergence of Filters]

I have no clue to do it, 
Any insight ? Hope to get a help as usual.
Thanks.

Comment: Check out [this page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pretopological+space) and the links therein.

Answer (score 1):

This is related to the notion of a [pretopolological space](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pretopological+space). For this we have a collection $\mathcal{C}$ of pairs $(\mathcal{F},x)$ as described. It's customary to write $ (\mathcal{F},x) \in \mathcal{C}$ as $\mathcal{F} \to x$.

A convergence relation that is defined by a topology in the usual way (a filter converges to $x$ iff it contains all neighbourhoods of $x$), has at least the following axioms:

(i) $\forall x \in X: \{A \subseteq X: x \in A\} \to x$ (the so-called fixed filter on $x$ converges to its common point. (all neighbourhoods of $x$ contain $x$).

(ii) If $\mathcal{F} \to x$ and $\mathcal{F} \subseteq \mathcal{G}$ then $\mathcal{G} \to x$ as well. (if $\mathcal{F}$ contains all neighbourhoods of $x$ then $\mathcal{G}$ certainly does as well)

(iii) Define for $x \in X$: $\mathcal{N}_x = \bigcap \{\mathcal{F}: \mathcal{F} \to x\}$. This is a filter on $X$ (all intersections of filters are filters). Then the axiom states $\mathcal{N}_x \to x$ for all $x \in X$.

Now define a set $O\subseteq X$ to be $\mathcal{C}$-open whenever $$\forall x \in O: \mathcal{F} \to x \implies O \in \mathcal{F}$$

and also define $N$ to be a topological neighbourhood of $x$ iff there is some $O$ which is $\mathcal{C}$-open such that $x \in O \subseteq N$. These form a filter $\mathcal{T}_x$.

Then we have that the $\mathcal{C}$-open sets (which always form a topology $\mathcal{T}_{\mathcal{C}}$) are exactly the topology such that $\mathcal{F} \to x$ iff $\mathcal{T}_x \subseteq \mathcal{F}$, so that this topology exactly gives the notion of convergence $\mathcal{C}$ , iff $\mathcal{N}_x = \mathcal{T}_x$ for all $x \in X$.

Unpacking definitions:

$$\forall x: \forall N \subseteq X \left((\exists O \subseteq X: (\forall \mathcal{F}:   (\mathcal{F} \to x) \implies O \in \mathcal{F}) \land x \in O \land O \subseteq N\right) \leftrightarrow N \in \bigcap \{\mathcal{F}: \mathcal{F} \to x\}$$

which is then the final (ugly) axiom to characterise topological convergences of filters. There is also an interior of the interior condition, which is probably nicer (but equivalent).

Proofs of this can be found [here](https://www.bioinf.uni-leipzig.de/~studla/Publications/PREPRINTS/01-pfs-007-subl1.pdf) e.g.